# Getting error "System IO.IOException: The directory name is invalid" while installing the App in iOS using Xamarin UI Test

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.uitest

I have already developed iOS app and **I have not used Xamarin to develop this app**. Now I am trying develop UI test cases for my App in iOS Using Xamarin UI test project. I am using Xamarin studio to develop my UI Test Cases in C#.

And I am trying to run the test case project using Mac machine.

Then I am facing error("System IO.IOException: The directory name is invalid") while installing my App using Xamarin test code. Below is the code snippet i am using to install my App in to iOS device.

```
IApp app = ConfigureApp.iOS .EnableLocalScreenshots() .DeviceIdentifier("f8c67472f88efb1985c2f5e73698d6bb36988f5d").AppBundle("..\app.ipa") .StartApp();
```

Path for my ipa is correct only.

Can any one please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

`AppBundle` is the directory containing the **`.app`** bundle, not the `.ipa`. I assume you are using Xcode, so your `.app` is going to be located in the `DerivedData` folder unless you mod'ed the build output.

You can also use `.InstalledApp({Your app's Bundle ID})` instead, but you will need to install the `.ipa` on the device before running the tests.

Note: Whether you use the app or spa, just make sure that it is [linked](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios#step-1-link-calabashframework) against `calabash.framework`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Sushil. Using InstalledApp method I am able to connect to the already installed App. But Can i install the .ipa file(App) on the iOS device using Xamarin UI Test code?

Comment: You would need to use the `.app` via AppBundle to have xamarin uitest install it. There are ways to install a ipa from the cmd line, a SO or Google search will show the different ways..